# Salesforce CRM Content User

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there a API name for "Salesforce CRM Content User" checkbox on user object?
I want to set it as True in my trigger for all new users but i can't find out its api name.

Answer (score 3):

I think the permission you are looking for is called:

> UserPermissionsSFContentUser

So in your trigger, set this value to True on your user and you should be set!